# Title Page with LaTeX

Tags: titles

**Output**

I obtained the following output with code given below:

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside,english,a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{a4wide, fullpage, color, fancyhdr, lastpage, changepage, multirow, calligra, graphicx}    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm}

\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@fancy% Plain page style = fancy page style
\makeatother

\providecommand*{\wb}[2]{\fontsize{#1}{#2}\usefont{U}{webo}{xl}{n}}
\newcommand*{\cdiam}{\prec\kern-2pt\succ}
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\fontfamily{pbk}\selectfont  
\begin{adjustwidth*}{1.5cm}{2cm}
    \vspace*{4.5\baselineskip}
    \centering
    \begin{picture}(600, 0)
      \multiput(0, 110)(20, 0){20}{{\wb{10}{12}4}}                    % Top Line
      \multiput(-5, 90)(0,-21){35}{\rotatebox{90}{{\wb{10}{12}4}}}    % Left Line
      \multiput(0,-630)(20, 0){20}{{\wb{10}{12}4}}                    % Bottom Line
      \multiput(400,90)(0,-21){35}{\rotatebox{90}{{\wb{10}{12}4}}}    % Right Line
    \end{picture}
    \end{adjustwidth*}  
  \end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

I want to move the left border to more left and right border to more right. Also the bottom border is not joining with right and left border. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: this is not a minimal example. A lot of the packages that are in there don't seem to have anything to do with your issue. As for that issue: what happens when you modify the coordinates you specified in your picture environment?

Comment: @NilsL: My apologies if my MWE has extra packages. I tried my best. Would you mind to tell me what packages are extra here? Thanks

Comment: here's a helpful guide to creating minimal working examples: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that ...you may also want to have a look at this introduction to the `picture` environment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Picture#The_picture_environment_and_gnuplot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have the specified font so the border shows up as a string of the number 4. I decreased the size of the margins, and made a couple of other changes, noted in the code. You can probably tweak it to get what you need.  I'm not sure if I provided exactly what you were looking for but you can tweak the coordinates as noted by @NilsL in the comments. I removed several of the packages that didn't appear necessary to this specific problem.

**Edit**: Used original margins, adjusted coordinates.

```
\documentclass[oneside,english,a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{a4wide, changepage, graphicx}    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm}

\providecommand*{\wb}[2]{\fontsize{#1}{#2}\usefont{U}{webo}{xl}{n}}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\fontfamily{pbk}\selectfont  
\begin{adjustwidth*}{1.5cm}{2cm}
    \vspace*{4.5\baselineskip}
    \centering
    \begin{picture}(600, 0)
      \multiput(-35, 110)(20, 0){25}{{\wb{10}{12}4}}                    % Top Line
      \multiput(-40, 90)(0,-21){35}{\rotatebox{90}{{\wb{10}{12}4}}}    % Left Line
      \multiput(-35,-630)(20, 0){25}{{\wb{10}{12}4}}                    % Bottom Line
      \multiput(460,90)(0,-21){35}{\rotatebox{90}{{\wb{10}{12}4}}}    % Right Line
    \end{picture}
    \end{adjustwidth*}  
  \end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1): Thanks @2cat for your nice answer. Can we get the same output without changing `lmargin,rmargin` or this change only affects the title page. Thanks

Comment: Sure, see the edits above. All you have to do is adjust the coordinates to position each line where you need it.