# Installing missing fonts in Texlive on Ubuntu

Tags: fonts, titles, windows, ubuntu

I switched from `Windows 7` to `Ubuntu 14.04`. The following code was producing this [output](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/193013/4821).

```
\documentclass[oneside,english,a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{a4wide, fullpage, color, fancyhdr, lastpage, changepage, multirow, calligra, graphicx}    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm}

\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@fancy% Plain page style = fancy page style
\makeatother

\providecommand*{\wb}[2]{\fontsize{#1}{#2}\usefont{U}{webo}{xl}{n}}
\newcommand*{\cdiam}{\prec\kern-2pt\succ}
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\fontfamily{pbk}\selectfont  
\begin{adjustwidth*}{1.5cm}{2cm}
    \vspace*{4.5\baselineskip}
    \centering
    \begin{picture}(600, 0)
      \multiput(0, 110)(20, 0){20}{{\wb{10}{12}4}}                    % Top Line
      \multiput(-5, 90)(0,-21){35}{\rotatebox{90}{{\wb{10}{12}4}}}    % Left Line
      \multiput(0,-630)(20, 0){20}{{\wb{10}{12}4}}                    % Bottom Line
      \multiput(400,90)(0,-21){35}{\rotatebox{90}{{\wb{10}{12}4}}}    % Right Line
    \end{picture}
    \end{adjustwidth*}  
  \end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

But now on `Ubuntu 14.04` I'm getting output with the border shows up as a string of the number 4. I would highly appreciate if someone guide me how to install the required fonts. Thanks

Comment: Did you install TeXlive on terminal or from the repository? If yes, use on terminal `sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-recommended`. If you installed from the iso image, use lmgr` to install packages. If you press tab you can automplete and see that there are other fonts.

Comment: Thanks @Sigur for your interest in my problem. I used `sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-recommended` through terminal and getting `texlive-fonts-recommended is already the newest version.
texlive-fonts-recommended set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.`. There is no change. Any thoughts.

Comment: Type `texlive-fonts-` and press TAB to see other packages.

Comment: What works for me, for almost all fonts, is this: `apt-get install texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-fonts-extra`. From Tahtisilma's answer, it looks like the specific font being asked about in this question has a more specific issue due to licensing.

Comment: This post indicates how to install (a) latex font (fonts) from CTAN to TexLive manually: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/350205/213

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Webomint font is not provided in Ubuntu distribution due to license hassle. The simplest way to install this font is to use:

```
wget http://tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/install-getnonfreefonts
sudo texlua install-getnonfreefonts
getnonfreefonts -a
```

If you want to know more details see [here](http://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/)

Comment: (+1): Thanks a lot @Tahtisilma for your nice answer. You provided solution worked like a charm. Thank again.

Comment: @MYaseen208 It would be better to use `getnonfreefonts-sys` to install the fonts so that you do not need to manually update your font stuff every time the `texlive` packages are updated. However, I'm not sure how this works with Ubuntu's version of TeX Live.

Comment: @Tahtisilma: After upgrading to `Texlive 2014` on `Unbutu 14.04`  I'm getting this error (for some files):
`!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file WebOMintsGD): Font WebOMintsGD not found`. Any idea to fix this problem. Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208 The files were installed in texmf-local, after you upgraded the texmf-local is reused, but the map files in it is not activated, you will need to do that by hand.